# Proving convergence in prob implies convergence in dist.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I'm following the proof in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY2WG7xM76I&t=195s), but I am confused with one of the steps. (3:21)

Why is the following true?

$$[X_n \leq x] + [X_n>x,-X \geq -x + \varepsilon] \leq [X_n \leq x]+ [X_n-X \geq \varepsilon] $$

Or in simplier terms why is the following true?

$$[X_n>x,-X \geq -x + \varepsilon] \leq [X_n-X \geq \varepsilon] $$

Comment: what video${}$?

Comment: Apologies - added the link.

Comment: It is actually $[X_n > x, -X \geq -x+\epsilon]$ in the second term LHS, thats why it works.

Comment: Thanks I edited my post. However I still can't see how this is larger because the inequalities are different on both sides.

Comment: See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propA2

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite $[X_n>x,-X\geq -x+\varepsilon]$ as $[X_n>x,X\leq x-\varepsilon]$.

If $X_n>x$ and $X\leq x-\varepsilon$ then also $X_n-X>\varepsilon$. Since $X_n-X>\varepsilon$ occurs whenever $X_n>x,X\leq x-\varepsilon$ occurs, its probability is at least as high.